# Insertar valores en mysql desde tkinter

Tags: mysql, tkinter, python-3.7

Muy buenas, estoy intentando crear un usuario por defecto en mi programa. Hasta donde he averiguado, los valores están escritos correctamente. No se cual es mi error. Por favor si me puden ayudar les estaré agradecido.

La terminal me arroja el código de error:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

```
def login ():
    conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor()
    cursor1.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuario (Nombre text, Apellido text, Cedula int, Contraseña text)")
    
    insertar_usuario=(''' INSERT INTO Usuario (Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Contraseña) Values (%S, %S, %S, %S) ''' )
    usuario1=("Jorge", "III", 1776, "perro23")
    cursor1.execute(insertar_usuario, usuario1)
    cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM Usuario where Nombre=? AND Contraseña=?", (caja_u.get(), caja_c.get()))
    row=cursor1.fetchone()
    if row: 
        caja_u.delete(0, END)
        caja_c.delete(0, END)
        session()
        print("Sesion iniciada")
        
    else:
        label_datos_incorrectos=customtkinter.CTkLabel(marco, text="Datos incorrectos")
        label_datos_incorrectos.grid(column=0, row=4) 

    conn.commit() 
    conn.close()´´´
```

Comment: No parece faltar ningun parametro la los querys que haces. Seguro que el fallo está en el código publicado?

Comment: Si hermano, la terminal me señala específicamente esta linea:  cursor1.execute(insertar_usuario, usuario1)

Comment: No se mucho de mysql, pero puede ser que en lugar de %S vaya %s (con la s minuscula)?

Comment: No hay problema Dante, igual muchas gracias. Se que contestaste a mi última pregunta. No veo por ningún lado algo para dar like, pero si existe te daría like.

Comment: Gracias por tu intención! Si quieres puedes darle un +1 a mi comentario si quieres agradecerme de alguna manera (aunque eso no recompensa a ninguno de los dos)